# Drupal: customizing validation error messages

Tags: drupal, validation

When the user submits a custom CCK form and a field marked as `REQUIRED` is empty, I get an `xyz field is required.`.
How can I customize this message without modifying core modules?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the error message and how you need to change it, you may be able to use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to replace the string used to generate the message.

Another option is to create a custom module that overrides the [validation function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate) for a particular form or field, replacing any error messages with the messages of your choosing.

Comment: i was hoping for a property like ['#error_message'] to be set :-(