# Drupal form api customize error messages

Tags: forms, drupal, message

How can i customize the core error message that Drupal renders for a form with elements having "required" property as TRUE.

When i use _validate hook the messages in the form do not override the Drupal default messages for form.

Thanks,
Aniruddh

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions for help:

- [Drupal: customizing validation error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830379/drupal-customizing-validation-error-messages)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20844/is-it-possible-to-customize-site-status-messages.

There are some modules for that: [Custom Submit Messages](https://drupal.org/project/csm), [StringOverrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).

If you need to **alter the form** you have to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function or similar ([hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7), [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)). And for #validate element there is a notice:

> If you are altering an existing form via hook_form_alter() or a similar means, be careful with this property! You will probably want to add to the existing array rather than writing over it, so don't follow this usage example exactly.

Comment: Did you find a solution from this answer? If so please select it as a correct one or upvote it.